# How to rename FunctionDecl in clangAST?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

I use child class from lang::RecursiveASTVisitor to traverse clang AST and rename function from one name to another. I use rewriter class for it

```
/// \brief rename function declarations
virtual bool VisitFunctionDecl(clang::FunctionDecl *func) {
    std::string funcName = func->getNameInfo().getName().getAsString();
    if (funcName == _nameFrom) {
        _rewriter.ReplaceText(func->getLocation(), (int)funcName.length(), _nameTo);

    }
    return true;
}
```

and similar one for function calls.

But this approach renames functions in source code. I can get new version of code (with new function names), but the names of the current ast nodes are still the same. Can I somehow rename the ast nodes itself?

Comment: Have you tried using [`setDeclName`](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1NamedDecl.html#aeb59a31c670e562254b2abd917e58a13)?

Comment: Thanks, but could you provide an example of how I can initialize DeclarationName instance to pass in setDeclName? I can't find anything for setting that class from string.